# Getting Invalid hook call for uniswap widget

Tags: uniswap, react

I want to include [Uniswap widget](https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/widgets/swap-widget) in my DApp (in React) but somehow I am getting this error in console due to which other components are also not rendering:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1476:1)
    at useContext (react.development.js:1484:1)
    at Fe (ThemeProvider.js:47:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
```

May someone knows what I am doing wrong ? Here's my files:

`Uniswap-widget/index.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import { SwapWidget } from '@uniswap/widgets'
import '@uniswap/widgets/fonts.css'

function UniSwapWidget() {
  return (
    <div className="Uniswap">
      <SwapWidget />
    </div>
  );
}

export default UniSwapWidget;
```

`App.js`:

```
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import UniSwapWidget from "./components/Uniswap-widget";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Navbar/>
     <UniSwapWidget/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this, by downgrading the `react` and `react-dom` version of my main application.

Uniswap widget uses `React@^17.0.1` while the app was on `18`.

Code to fix:

`yarn remove react react-dom && yarn add react@^17.0.1 react-dom@^17.0.1`

Do note that you will have to make some changes in index file of your project after this.